# I am trying to build a single c++ project in Eclipse but getting the build error even if after setting the path variable with mingw path

Tags: c++, eclipse

When click the `buildall` option in eclipse I am facing below error and object file is not getting created

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\helloworld.o ..\src\helloworld.cpp
Internal Builder: Cannot run program "g++"
```

Comment: And you have `g++` installed? And in the path (or told Eclipse where to find it)?

Comment: yes.. i have g++ in that path.I added the path variable where i have mention the path for g++

Comment: I mean the `PATH`, where the system searches for commands. If you open a command prompt and run the command `g++` does it work? Where *is* `g++` installed?

Comment: I never realized there's a place in the universe where Eclipse works with C++ and people (or aliens) really use it... I'm shocked to my very core!

Comment: Is it possible that you changed the PATH variable *after* you started eclipse? Then you would of course need to restart eclipse (in the terminal where you changed the PATH variable).

Comment: @Rene, thanks its working after restart.. but it is now facing execution error

Answer (score 0):

Put complete path of c++ compiler present in the `mingw`, in the enviroment variable of eclipse. Then close the IDE and restart it .